# System.DmlException: Insert failed. CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, INVALID_FIELD_FOR_INSERT_UPDATE, cannot specify Id in an insert call: [Id]

Tags: trigger, after-trigger

I have written a triggers on object `Job__c` as well as `Employee__c`, so that when an Job record is created an Employee record would be created an vice-verce

> createEmp: execution of AfterInsert caused by: System.DmlException:
> Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY,
> createJob: execution of AfterInsert caused by: System.DmlException: Insert failed.
> First exception on row 0 with id a025i000006jOCEAA2;
> first error: INVALID_FIELD_FOR_INSERT_UPDATE, cannot specify Id in an insert call: [Id]

```apex
trigger createEmp on Job__c (after insert, after update) {
    List<Employee__c> empList = new List<Employee__c>();
    for(Job__c job: Trigger.new){
        Employee__c emp = new Employee__c();          
        if(job.counter__c == false){
            emp.Job__c = job.id; //lookup
            emp.Name = job.EmployeeName__c;
            emp.Salary__c = job.Salary__c;
            empList.add(emp);
        }
    }
    insert empList; 
}
```

```apex
trigger createJob on Employee__c (after insert, after update) {
    List<Job__c> jobList = new List<Job__c>();
    for(Employee__c emp: Trigger.new){
        Job__c job = new Job__c();
        if(emp.counter__c == false){
            job.id = emp.Job__c;
            job.EmployeeName__c = emp.Name;
            job.Salary__c = emp.Salary__c;
            jobList.add(job);
        }
    }
    insert jobList;
}
```

Comment: What does the field `counter__c` indicate for each object?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE)!

*Firstly*: You do not seem to be doing any check to see if a related record of the other object already exists before you insert it. Is that a possibility that you need to check for? Or is there a guaranteed 1-to-1 relationship between Job & Employee?  (If that 1-to-1 relationship is NOT guaranteed, you might want to consider a different approach entirely.)

*Secondly*: In your `createJob on Employee__c` trigger, in the first line of your `if` statement you are explicitly setting the `Id` for the object you are about to insert. In Salesforce the `Id` is created by the system upon insertion - you cannot specify the `Id` of a record you want to create.

Going by the code from your first trigger, you might want that line to be...

```apex
job.Emp__c = emp.Id;
```

...or you may need to figure out whatever other logice. But explicitly setting the `job.Id` when creating the Job record is not going to work.

*Thirdly*: Once you get it working, you should consider moving all of your trigger logic to helper classes.  You can find plenty about that all over SFSE, Trailhead and the general internet.